# Can I use a book SQL Tuning Experts which is for Oracle 10g to tune Oracle 9i?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know it is a little unusual, however I have a book on Oracle 10g performance tuning tools and techniques, the 9i version is not as readily available to me.

I need a book to start me off with the topic of performance tuning on 9i as my work mandates me to, am I able to follow the book on 10g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which book do you mean?

All the Oracle documentation is available for free online, with [Oracle 9r2 available here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db92/db92.homepage) and [Oracle 10r2 available here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage).

Many of the practices that you would use on 10g are probably still applicable for 9i although it would be looking at the [Oracle 10g Performance Tuning new features](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/whatsnew.htm#i974246) and the [Oracle 10g New Features Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14214/toc.htm) to work out what features are unavailable to you.

I find that Oracle 10g automates a lot more so many aspects of performance tuning are much easier, for example the SQL Tuning Advisor and SQL Profiles but in the main for actually tuning queries, a lot of the features are similar.